# How this while loop prints 3 as a value for cnt instead 2 when u enter the vlalue for number of students as 3?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm developing a Student Ranking System..

The variable `cnt` takes the value 3 instead 2, when I input 3 as no. of Student, only when I assign values to the array `artot`. here "cnt" and "count" are a local variables of main function which have there initial value as 0.IdGetter() just gets the id from user and assign it to "std_id",MarksGetter() gets the marks of a subject as the input and assign it to "sbt_marks".

```
for(;cnt<std_cnt;cnt++)
{
    IdGetter();
    while(count<sbt_cnt)
    {   
        MarksGetter();
        total=total+marks;
        count=count+1;
    }
    printf("%d\t%d\n",id,total);
    artot[cnt][0]=id;
    artot[cnt][1]=total;
    printf("cnt:%d\tcount:%d\n",cnt,count);
    count=0;
    total=0;
}
```

when I input a value for No. of students, the value of `cnt` variable  should be one less than the no. I entered.

Comment: You didn't mention how `cnt` was initialized.

Comment: I do not understand the problem, and the code is incomplete. What does `IdGetter()` do? What does `MarksGetter()` do? Where are all your variables initialized?  Please improve the question by posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking cnt value after loop's execution, then cnt=std_cnt because testing is done after incrementation in for loop's last iteration.